# What does edge-based and level-based mean?

Tags: kubernetes

What does  "level-based" and "edge-based" mean in general?

I read "In other words, the system's behavior is level-based rather than edge-based" from kubernetes documentation:
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/a7de9ec822008a2e5bc1a3761f8fdbd248d38dff/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#objects

with Google, I only find:
http://www.keil.com/forum/9423/edge-based-vs-level-based-interrupt/

Thank you.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/level-triggering-and-reconciliation-in-kubernetes-1f17fe30333d

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It also has a more general definition (at least the way we tend to use it in the documentation). A piece of logic is "level based" if it only depends on the current state. A piece of logic is "edge-based" if it depends on history/transitions in addition to the current state.

"Level based" components are more resilient because if they crash, they can come back up and just look at the current state. "Edge-based" components must store the history they rely on (or depend on some other component that stores it), so that when they come back up they can look at the current state and the history. Also, if there is some kind of temporary network partition and an edge-based component misses some of the updates, then it will compute the wrong output.

However, "level based" components are usually less efficient, because they may need to scan a lot of state in order to compute an output, rather than just reading deltas.

Many components are a mixture of the two.

Simple example: You want to build a component that reports the number of pods in READY state. A level-based implementation would fetch all the pods from etcd (or the API server) and count. An edge-based implementation would do that once at startup, and then just watch for pods entering and exiting READY state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they explained it pretty well on the site:

> When a new version of an object is POSTed or PUT, the "spec" is updated and available immediately. Over time the system will work to bring the "status" into line with the "spec". The system will drive toward the most recent "spec" regardless of previous versions of that stanza. **In other words, if a value is changed from 2 to 5 in one PUT and then back down to 3 in another PUT the system is not required to 'touch base' at 5 before changing the "status" to 3**.

So from that statement, we know that "*level base*" means a PUT request does not need to be satisfied if the primary goal does not require it; **it's free to skip PUT requests when seen fit**.

This makes me assume that "*edge based*" systems require every PUT request to be satisfied, even if some requests could be skipped without altering the final result, since that would be the alternative to skipping requests.

I'm no RESTful developer (you can see by my account activity). I could not find any source of information for these things anywhere else, so I'm going based on the explanation they gave, which seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes API doesn't store a history of all the changes made to an object. The controller that is responsible for that object cannot reliably observe each change; it may only observe the current state of the object.

The term "level" means the current state of the object, and the term "edge" means a transition to a new state. Controllers are "level-based" because they cannot reliably observe the transitions.

From the [API conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#spec-and-status):

> When a new version of an object is POSTed or PUT, the spec is updated and available immediately. Over time the system will work to bring the status into line with the spec. The system will drive toward the most recent spec regardless of previous versions of that stanza. For example, if a value is changed from 2 to 5 in one PUT and then back down to 3 in another PUT the system is not required to 'touch base' at 5 before changing the status to 3. In other words, the system's behavior is level-based rather than edge-based. This enables robust behavior in the presence of missed intermediate state changes.